# How to lower or higher the volume of music in Spotify SDK Swift

Tags: swift, spotify, libspotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, spotify-desktop

I'm working on a simple app that allows a user to sign in with his/her spotify account and then plays a song after user authentication. I tried following the spotify-provided tutorial, but i am really confused how to get volume and how to set low or high volume of music. I found two function method:

**First function**

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didSeekToPosition position: TimeInterval) {
}
```

**Second function**

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didChangeVolume volume: SPTVolume) {
}
```

But i am confused how to use this function and how to get volume through this functions? if any other function through get volume or set high or low volume please let me known.

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , i've tried to solve this issue but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That looks more like callbacks functions in a delegate protocol

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Any idea ?? please let me know how to get volume

Comment: In the second function, didChangeVolume is the value that should be assigned to the volume. What exactly isn’t working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`volume` is a property on `SPTAudioStreamingController` object](https://spotify.github.io/ios-streaming-sdk/Classes/SPTAudioStreamingController.html#//api/name/volume), so to get the current volume you simply need to get a reference to your `SPTAudioStreamingController` and then read the `volume` off of that.

Then, to reset the volume, you can use [`SPTAudioStreamingController`'s `setVolume:callback:` function](https://spotify.github.io/ios-streaming-sdk/Classes/SPTAudioStreamingController.html#//api/name/setVolume:callback:).

And if it works, I suspect that second delegate method you pointed to in your question will fire, but you can also use the callback to detect whether an error happened.